# Similarities and differences between conjunctions and conditionals

Tags: logic

What are the similarities and differences between the conjunction ("and") and the conditional ("If...then") truth functions ?

Comment: That’s an awfully vague question; what sorts of similarities and differences do you haved in mind?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Just general

Comment: @BrianM.Scott As in basic similarities or differences, obvious ones that stand out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another similarity is that both of these connectives are used to restrict quantifiers. Specifically, consider quantified statements, like $\forall x\,P(x)$ and $\exists x\,P(x)$.  If I want to restrict the variable $x$ to range only over things that satisfy some restriction $R(x)$ (so I want to say "everything that satisfies $R$ has the property $P$" or "something that satisfies $R$ has the property $P$"), then I would use the formulas $\forall x\,[R(x)\to P(x)]$ and $\exists x\,[R(x)\land P(x)]$.  That is, universally quantified variables are restricted by means of implications, and existentially quantified variables are restricted by means of conjunctions.

On a rather different level, another similarity is that both of these connectives are introduced in categorical logic as right adjoints. Bringing that down to (or near) earth, this means the following. $p\land q$ is the least amount of information from which you can infer $p$ and you can also infer $q$.  $p\to q$ is the least amount of information from which, if you know $p$, you can infer $q$.  (Contrast with the simplest such description of disjunction: $p\lor q$ is the *most* information that you can infer from $p$ and can also infer from $q$.)

Answer (score 1):

There really isn’t much of significance to say. They’re both binary connectives, they both take one truth value in three cases and the other in just one case (though for $\land$ it’s three false and one true, while for $\to$ it’s three true and one false), and neither is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Let K denote logical conjunction and C the conditional.  If you check the two-valued truth tables for both of them, you can figure out that {X(x, y), x} |= y holds for all X belonging to {K, C}.  In words "if X(x, y) holds as true, and so does x, then y will hold as true also," holds for both K and C.  On the other hand, there do exist tautologies which just have lower case letters and C's, but there do NOT exist any tautologies which just have lower case letters and K's.  Cxx, or (xCx) or xxC or (x)C(x) holds as a tautology however you want to write it, but Kxx does not.  However, for all x in the set of truth values {0, 1}, the value of Kxx equals x, so there exists some x such that Cxx does not equal x.

In natural deduction systems introduction and elimination rules for the connectives K and C usually *vastly* differ.

Usually one has rules for the K connective which say something like:

"From K$\alpha$$\beta$, we may infer $\alpha$."

"From K$\alpha$$\beta$, we may infer $\beta$."

"From $\alpha$, as well as $\beta$, we may infer K$\alpha$$\beta$."

Usually one has rules corresponding to the C connective which say something like:

"From C$\alpha$$\beta$, as well as $\alpha$, we may infer $\beta$."

"From a deduction which starts with $\alpha$ and ends with $\beta$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have exactly the same scope, we may infer C$\alpha$$\beta$."

All tautologies which start with K also come as longer than the shortest tautology which starts with C, the wff Cpp.  Also, for every tautology which starts with K, if the first two rules here make sense for K, then such a tautology $\tau$ contains two tautologies $\phi$ and $\zeta$ both distinct from $\tau$.  Some tautologies which start with C do not contain any tautologies distinct from themselves.  Neither K, nor C with just variables can represent all two-valued truth-functions.